# How do I recruit more pilots?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I kind of.... killed all my pilots in carrer  mode in .90, so can someone tell me how to get more? Also i have a whole bunch of scientists and engineers if converting the traits of them is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the astronaut lounge just spawn a random batch of astronauts each time you start the game?

Answer (score 7):

Should all your crewmembers fall victim to unfortunate accidents, you can always recruit more at the astronaut complex. Should the astronaut complex run out of applicants of the right class, just go to the tracking station and speed up time. After a few days new applicants will appear, eagerly waiting for you to hire them and send to heaven in the name of science.

When all your available slots for active astronauts are filled with non-pilots, you can also use the astronaut complex to sack any who are not on a mission. When the kerbal you want to get rid of is currently on a flight, you can terminate that flight in the tracking station. Any kerbals on the flight will then be listed as "Lost" in the astronaut complex and will no longer occupy a slot.

The class of an astronaut is determined when they spawn as applicants in the astronaut complex. It can not be changed.

Comment: thank you but is there a way to get rid of applicants?

Comment: @the.blue.emrald Unhired applicants will also be replaced after a few days.

Comment: is there a more scientific definition of 'a few days'? I've been waiting for them to cycle for some time now...